# What is the alternative to Time.time for scrolling texture?

Tags: unity

In my game, I'm using the standard SetTextureOffset method to smoothly scroll texture on background quad.

However, on game over, instead of reloading the scene, I'm just reseting all values initial position to give illusion that scene was reloaded. With this approash, i'm unable to use Time.time or Time.timeSinceLevelLoad because, the level was not reloaded and this value stays high. So scrolling is too fast right in the beginning.

Are there any time independent methods to smoothly scroll texture? Thanks.

Comment: I would be more inclined to use Mathf.Repeat to alter the texture offset based on the Time.time... This would eliminate the bug you are experiencing... You can limit the repeat method to return a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Tried it. Scrolling is not smooth. The only smooth scrolling I'm getting is when I use one of the time functions.

Comment: I am telling you to use a time function... But the value you should input into the offset should be the value returned by the repeat method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering, I found Time.time,Time.timeSinceLevelLoaded were the ones working fine. They had the property of increasing linearly.
So I used a float variable "damp" which is incremented by a small value e.g damp+=0.1f;
Now it works smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Time.time - timeSinceReset
```

and when you "reset" you set it to `timeSinceReset = Time.time;`

Comment: It should work, but the scrolling is not smooth, visibly jerky.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoRoutines instead of Time.time

```
void IEnumerators( float x )
{
    //x is your time delay. in your code, x=Time.time-lastScrolledTime
    yield return new WaitForSecond(x);
    //scroll texture here
}
```